# Symfony 3 - Navbar showing correctly on every page but one?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

Hi guys I'm developing an app in Symfony 3 which has a navbar. The navbar is extended on every page, and displays correctly on every page as seen. The navbar uses bootstrap's css for designing a navbar.

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/css/bootstrap.css') }}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/illnessPage.css') }}"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="art">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Arthritis Care</h1>
        <p>You have signed up to the app with your specified illness being Arthritis.</p>
        <p>Try exploring our app</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="column1">
                Arthritis Care & Exercises
                </div>
                <img src="../images/arthritisHands.png" alt="Hands With Arthritis" height="300" width="350">
            </div>
             <div class="col-sm">
                 <div class="column2">
                     Arthritis Ireland
                 </div>
                 <img src="../images/artIreland.png" alt="Arthritis Ireland Logo" height="300" width="350">
             </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="column3">
                    Useful Numbers & Information
                </div>
                <img src="../images/redphone.png" alt="Red Phone" height="300" width="350">
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

And it works like this for every other page. But for this one page it is displaying the navbar's options, but not the css? Does anyone know the reason for this?

```
{# default/scheduler.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}

<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{{ asset("libraries/dhtmlx/codebase/dhtmlxscheduler_flat.css") }}' charset="utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/scheduler.css') }}"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block body -%}

<div id="scheduler_element" class="dhx_cal_container" style='width:100%; height:600px;'>
    <div class="dhx_cal_navline">
        <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_today_button"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="day_tab" style="right:204px;"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab" style="right:140px;"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="month_tab" style="right:76px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_header"></div>
    <div class="dhx_cal_data"></div>
</div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
<!-- Include the scheduler library -->
<script src='{{ asset("libraries/dhtmlx/codebase/dhtmlxscheduler.js") }}' type='text/javascript' charset="utf-8"></script>

<!-- Include jQuery to handle AJAX Requests -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include Momentjs to play with the dates -->
<script src="{{ asset("libraries/momentjs/moment.js") }}"></script>

<script>

    window.GLOBAL_APPOINTMENTS = {{ appointments|raw }};


    window.GLOBAL_SCHEDULER_ROUTES = {
        create: '{{ path("scheduler_create") }}',
        update: '{{ path("scheduler_update") }}',
        delete: '{{ path("scheduler_delete") }}'
    };

    window.GLOBAL_CATEGORIES = {{ categories|raw }};
</script>

<!-- Include the schedulerScripts that you will need to write in the next step -->
<script src='{{ asset("libraries/schedulerScripts.js") }}' type='text/javascript' charset="utf-8"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

The navbar twig template for reference

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />

{% block title %}Health Centre Ireland{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/css/bootstrap.css') }}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
{% endblock %}
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('redcross.ico') }}" />
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
<a class="navbar-brand" a href="#">Health Centre Ireland</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarsExampleDDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('login') }}">Home <span class="sr-only"></span> </a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path ('scheduler') }}">Calender</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Message Board</a>
        </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                {% if app.user %}
                <a class="nav-link" href="
                    {{ logout_path('main') }}">
                        Log Out</a>
                {% else %}
                <a class="nav-link" href="
                {{ path ('login') }}">
                    Log In</a>
                {% endif %}

        <li class="nav-item">
            {% if app.user %}
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('deleteuser') }}"> Delete Account</a>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <img class="redcross"
         src="../images/redcross.png" height="40" width="40">
</div>

{% if app.session.flashBag.has('success') %}
    <div class ="alert alert-success">
        {% for msg in app.session.flashBag.get('success') %}
            {{ msg }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
</nav>

{% block body %}{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your template, your erase the content of the `stylesheets` block.

You have to call the `{{ parent() }}` twig function to inherit from the base template:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{{ asset("libraries/dhtmlx/codebase/dhtmlxscheduler_flat.css") }}' charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/scheduler.css') }}"/>
{% endblock %}
```

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/extends.html#child-template

Comment: Thanks for the help man :). Such a small thing, but it makes a huge difference!